# Bootstrap background-image with CSS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

In bootstrap, i can use class=img-responsive to make sure that my image displays fully without being cropped out. How do i implement this "class=img-responsive" in my CSS stylesheet instead so that my background image will display fully?

This is my HTML file

```
<header class="bgimage">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Headline</h1>  
  </div>
</header>
```

This is my CSS Style sheet.

```
.bgimage {
  background-image: url('../images/tara1.jpg');
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following:

```
.bgimage{
  background-image: url('../images/tara1.jpg');
  background-size:100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 200px;
}
```

Think of setting an width, otherwise i think the percentage won't work :)